# how to find data volume size for a specific process group in NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to NiFi. We have a complex NiFi data flow in our organization. We have segregated different projects data flow into Process Groups. I was asked to find the data volume for a specific project (Process Group in NiFi) for a given period of time? How to find it in NiFi Web UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Apache NiFi User Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#monitoring) has a section on monitoring components and data flow. By default, a processor/process group will display the total amount of data processed by that component over the last 5 minutes. There are also [Reporting Tasks](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Reporting_Tasks) which allow the transmission of such monitoring data to external destinations.

[image: NiFi processor status with annotations]